# Why is the Jacobson radical of the integers $\{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why is the Jacobson radical of the integers $\{0\}$?

I have been working through questions dealing with the Jacobson radical and have come across this and can't think of why this would be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the simple $\mathbb{Z}$-modules? If you know the simple $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, it is easy to find their respective annihilators, and then the intersection of all these annihilators is easily seen to be $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element $x$ belongs to the Jacobson radical of a ring $R$ if and only if, for every $r\in R$, $1-xr$ is invertible.

If $R=\mathbb{Z}$, this implies that $1-x\cdot1=1$ or $1-x\cdot1=-1$, and $1-x\cdot(-1)=1$ or $1-x\cdot(-1)=-1$. So
$$
\text{($x=0$ or $x=2$) and ($x=0$ or $x=-2$)}
$$
and therefore $x=0$.

Comment: What was you reasoning for choosing r as -1 or 1, is this just an example that can be applied to any number? Also have you chosen x=0 as your final answer because x=0 is in both brackets in the previous line?

Comment: @user230498 The condition holds for *any* $r$, so why not choosing the easier numbers to start with? And yes, both brackets are true, so the only possibility is $x=0$: choosing $x=2$ would make the second false.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If an integer is divided by all prime numbers, then it is zero.